# Extend the clickable area to author name in authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

With the `authoryear` style the when using hyperref only the year is "clickable" but not the author. What should I change so to have a sigle clickable area author+year?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{dummybib}
\begin{document}
\cite{dummyentry}
\end{document}
```